# PHP newbie CURL and array

Tags: arrays, curl, php, getimagesize

UPDATED: I've simplified the code (tried to)

I'm trying to download a series of images as set in an array, but something is clearly not right:

```
function savePhoto($remoteImage,$fname) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $remoteImage);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    $fileContents = curl_exec($ch);
    $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if($retcode==200) {
        $newImg = imagecreatefromstring($fileContents);
        imagejpeg($newImg, ".{$fname}.jpg",100);
    }
    return $retcode;
}

$filesToGet = array('009');
$filesToPrint = array();

foreach ($filesToGet as $file) {
        if(savePhoto('http://pimpin.dk/jpeg/'.$file.'.jpg',$file)==200) {
            $size = getimagesize(".".$file.".jpg");
            echo $size[0] . " * " . $size[1] . "<br />";
        }
}
```

I get the following errors:

> Warning: imagecreatefromstring()
>   [function.imagecreatefromstring]:
>   Empty string or invalid image in
>   C:\inetpub\vhosts\dehold.net\httpdocs\ripdw\index.php
>   on line 15
>
> Warning: imagejpeg(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid Image resource
>   in
>   C:\inetpub\vhosts\dehold.net\httpdocs\ripdw\index.php
>   on line 16
>
> Warning: getimagesize(.009.jpg)
>   [function.getimagesize]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory
>   in
>   C:\inetpub\vhosts\dehold.net\httpdocs\ripdw\index.php
>   on line 26
>   *

Comment: Hi both! I've updated the question :-)

This is my first Q here on stack, so I hope you bear with me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead:

```
function get_file1($file, $local_path, $newfilename)
{
    $err_msg = '';
    echo "<br>Attempting message download for $file<br>";
    $out = fopen($newfilename, 'wb');
    if ($out == FALSE){
      print "File not opened<br>";
      exit;
    }

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);

    curl_exec($ch);
    echo "<br>Error is : ".curl_error ( $ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    //fclose($handle);

}//end function
```

// taken from: http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4009.html

or [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't save the file as a JPEG, and I would really like to get my piece of code to work (and hopefully understand what I'm doing wrong) :-)
Thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

You should try file_get_contents in replacement of CURL (simpler but it does the job):

```
 function savePhoto($remoteImage,$fname) {        
      $fileContents = file_get_contents($remoteImage);        
      try {        
        $newImg = imagecreatefromstring($fileContents);
        imagejpeg($newImg, ".{$fname}.jpg",100);        
      } catch (Exception $e) {        
        //what to do if the url is invalid        
      } 
}
```

Comment: That did help with saving the file, but it returns an error if the file doesn't exist and a 404 is returned:

...
Warning: file_get_contents(http://pimpin.dk/jpeg/00x9.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\inetpub\vhosts\dehold.net\httpdocs\ripdw\index.php on line 22...

Is it possible to prevent it?

Comment: Yeah, put your $fileContents = file_get_contents($remoteImage); in the try.
If it fails (in case of a 404) then your catch instructions will be processed without throwing a Warning (unless you DO throw an exception in your catch, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work, with help from you all and a bit of snooping around :-)

I ended up using CURL:

```
function savePhoto($remoteImage,$fname) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $remoteImage);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    $fileContents = curl_exec($ch);

    $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($ch);
    if($retcode == 200) {
        $newImg = imagecreatefromstring($fileContents);
        imagejpeg($newImg, $fname.".jpg",100);
    }

    return $retcode;
}


$website = "http://www.pimpin.dk/jpeg";
$filesToGet = array('009');
$filesToPrint = array();

foreach ($filesToGet as $file) {
        if(savePhoto("$website/$file.jpg",$file)==200) {
            $size = getimagesize($file.".jpg");
            echo $size[0] . " * " . $size[1] . "<br />";
        } else {
            echo "File wasn't found";
        }
}
```